# Jaxb XML marshaling ISO20022

Tags: jaxb

I try to generate (java 6) xml file which should have as a root:

```
<Document xmlns=”urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03”
xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”>
```

I have package-info is like below

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03",
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns={
        @XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"),         
        @XmlNs(prefix="xsi", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")        
    }
)
```

I get xml file like this

```
<ns2:Document xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"   xmlns:ns3="inner">
    <ns2:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <ns2:GrpHdr>..........
        ..............
    </ns2:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</ns2:Document>
```

I have no idea what is wrong.